# FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform CRUD operations on Reactjs Firebase app, but it is showing the following error
FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]:: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

I have tried many solutions all of them are related to firebase/firestore/lite.

*firebase-config.js*

```
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "some-key",
      authDomain: "auth-domain",
      projectId: some-projectId,
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: "",
    };

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
export { db };
```

*index.js*

```js
    import {
      collection,
      query,
      onSnapshot,
      addDoc,
      Timestamp,
    } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { db } from "../../firebase-config";
    import * as React from "react";
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

        export default function MortgageCard() {
           const [mortgages, setMortgages] = useState([])
           useEffect(() => {
    console.log("db connection: ", db);
             const q = query(collection(db, 'mortgage')) // app gets crashed here
             onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
               setMortgages(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                 id: doc.id,
                 data: doc.data()[enter image description here][1]
               })))
             })
           }
         ,[])
        }
```

*console.log(db)*

```
{
    "app": {
        "_isDeleted": false,
        "_options": {
            "apiKey": "AIzaSyCYCMv7wPaVC8J7RQo1LWCtGI0KjdGY25M",
            "authDomain": "anrack-d8e3d.firebaseapp.com",
            "projectId": "anrack-d8e3d",
            "storageBucket": "anrack-d8e3d.appspot.com",
            "messagingSenderId": "1000495980159",
            "appId": "1:1000495980159:web:f2a3f38e084c377ac6694a"
        },
        "_config": {
            "name": "[DEFAULT]",
            "automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false
        },
        "_name": "[DEFAULT]",
        "_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false,
        "_container": {
            "name": "[DEFAULT]",
            "providers": {}
        }
    },
    "databaseId": {
        "projectId": "anrack-d8e3d",
        "database": "(default)"
    },
    "settings": {
        "host": "firestore.googleapis.com",
        "ssl": true,
        "ignoreUndefinedProperties": false,
        "cacheSizeBytes": 41943040,
        "experimentalForceLongPolling": false,
        "experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling": false,
        "useFetchStreams": true
    }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6DmS.jpg)

Comment: Have you imported `db` into your `index.js` file? You might be passing in `undefined` instead

Comment: hi @samthecodingman i have updated the question and you can see i have imported db from file and i have also added consol.log(db).